# Can't find other options in the "Ok Google" detection settings page

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, sony-xperia, ok-google

I have already re-installed the google app, factory reset my phone, but I still can't find more options fron the 'Ok Google detection' page.

This is what I see:

[image: Screenshot. showing just one option]

<sub>Click image for larger version</sub>

My Phone: Sony Xperia C3 Dual

Android version: 5.1.1 (lollipop)

Comment: What the other opiton would be?

Comment: @Alex.S "from any screen" second is "Personal result"

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @DanHulme that i can use okay google any where even an application is open

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not all phones support hotword detection being on all the time (i.e. "OK Google" from any screen). The phone needs a lower-power co-processor, to avoid running down the battery by keeping the processor running at full power all the time just processing sounds. It's up to the system integrator (the people who compile Android for the phone) to set whether this option is enabled or not. [From other users' reports on Google Product Forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/GQZIgwPVU6A), it *looks like* the Xperia C3 doesn't support this, and Sony removed it in the update to Lollipop.

Most likely you could get this working with a custom ROM, but the cost would be that it would run down your battery - which is presumably why Sony removed the functionality in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for answering now i know why i cant get those options

Comment: Glide, if this answer is fine, award it the bounty!  As much as Dan needs it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Please update your default System language as English(US). It must work as Ok Google now supports only that. Go through this link ["OK Google from any screen missing!"](https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/websearch/xGiV6D4PMS8)

Comment: sorry for late response i already did that but same there is no other option apear

Answer (score 0):

You could flash OpenGApps nano over stock ROM, but it made Play services force close.

So, I tried flashing [deodexed stock ROM](https://mega.nz/#!thNXGZpJ!XbpF4Tr5Mx72wsQrHfom7USrr6T0sKpzsjBq5dTfmdc) and flashed OpenGApps over it, it worked.

*which means it doesn't require a custom ROM.*

Since you have Xperia C3 **DUAL** you should flash [this patch](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=3892287&d=1475393819) after deodex ROM.

To install a custom recovery without having to format your phone you can root using KingRoot and install *my modified* XZLockedDualRecovery and you can then flash SuperSU through recovery.

Using KingRoot and XZLDR installers requires enabling USB Debugging from developer options.

Sorry can't post more than two links.

For further instructions message me on fb.com/megaahmadf

Comment: [Kingroot](https://kingroot.net),

[XZLDR](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ann5aezdBLxQgYkVTAGDCyeT87IbCQ) look at guide.txt for instructions.

[SuperSU for Xperia C3](http://www.mediafire.com/file/ni2wtvzuy0gbw05/UPDATE-SuperSU-v1.99r3.zip)